# Сделать Button (кнопку) "неактивной" (без возможности отправить Touch Up Inside) в Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Добрый день! Хотелось бы познать как отключать Button (кнопку) при не выполнении условий типа if, и включать если те выполняются!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну здесь как бы другого и не дано:

```
btnSomeButton.enabled = (условие)
```

`Swift 3`:

```
btnSomeButton.isEnabled = (условие)
```

P.S.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Хотя можете по-другому записать:

```
if (условие) {
    btnSomeButton.enabled = true
} else {
    btnSomeButton.enabled = false
}

(условие) ? (btnLogin.enabled = true) : (btnLogin.enabled = false)
```

Comment: btnLogin.enabled = (условие)